# Running a react-native project causes PC to freeze

Tags: react-native, freeze

I've been trying to get started with react native development. I've followed the installation steps from the documentation, and all is well. But, when I try to run the app `react-native run-android`, my emulator freezes, and so is my entire PC, it barely responds to anything.

I've tried using my personal phone instead of a simulator, but I get the same results. Reinstalling react native didn't work either.

Looking at the Task Manager, I see that Disk usage is 100% or so. But I don't think my PC is old or bad, could this be the problem? Does it really demand high specs to run?

If it helps, this is what I get when I try to run it:

> C:\Users\Barak\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android info Starting
>
> JS server... info Installing the app...
>
> Task :app:installDebug 02:13:54 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
> 02:13:54 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554'
> : EOF hit. Read: -1 02:13:54 V/ddms: execute: returning Installing APK
>
> 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug 02:13:54
>
> D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>
> 02:13:54 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554' 02:13:54
>
> D/ddms: Reading file permision of
>
> C:\Users\Barak\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
>
> as: rwx------ 02:13:54 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t
>
> "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk" 02:13:55 V/ddms: execute 'pm install
>
> -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1 02:13:55 V/ddms: execute: returning 02:13:55 V/ddms: execute:
>
> running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk" 02:13:55 V/ddms: execute
>
> 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit.
> Read: -1 02:13:55 V/ddms: execute: returning Installed on 1 device.
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 55s 27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25
> up-to-date info Connecting to the development server... info Starting
> the app on "emulator-5554"... Starting: Intent {
> cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity } ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
> //You can see here I had to terminate it to get my PC to work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your problem it seems that your PC might not be fit for it. I had recently similar problem and adding extra RAM fixed it. It does not mean this is the solution for your problem.  The problem most likely is related to your hardware as otherwise it would be a common problem.

Cheers

Comment: I guess it could be it, I'll leave the question unanswered, as perhaps someone else will be able to think of a solution.

Comment: So I've bought an SSD, and it now works perfectly. Apparently that's all I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. It ran on my mobile device but it worked after some time. Try checking the port.

```
Run adb devices. Then  get your device name
run adb -s <device name> reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Then run react-native run-android.